# Tangent plane at a point on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tangent-spaces

In Pressley’s book, he writes since the tangent plane at $P$ in $S$ passes through the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is completely determined by giving a unit vector perpendicular to it called a unit normal to $S$ at $P$. Why must the tangent plane pass through the origin? Because it is a vector space spanned by the linearly independent partial derivative of a surface patch? Even if so why ‘passing through the origin’ plays a role in the plane being completely determined by a unit vector? Will it be impossible to do so if the plane didn’t pass through the origin?

Comment: What can be said is that the tangent plane in P, contains P.

Comment: So why does Pressley come to this conclusion? Am I missing something?

Comment: Or to put it this way? Is there any connection between a plane passing through origin and defining a unit normal?

Comment: Perhaps he is referring to a particular surface...

Comment: We want the tangent plane (or tangent space) at a point $P$ to be a vector subspace, because we're going to be doing linear algebra. Some books call this the tangent space and use the word tangent plane to refer to the translate of that plane to $P$.

Answer (score 1):

He said this to just identify the word "at $p$". Now the tangent plane is passing through the origin of $R^3$ which is $p$ itself. Thus, $R^3$ is a vector space with the origin at $p$ where the tangent space is a vector subspace generated by two tangent vectors to the surface at $p$. The unit normal is also at $p$.

You are dealing with two different but isometric 3-dimensional vector spaces $R^3$. The first is the one you are talking about and the second is the vector space generated by the tangent vectors and the normal vector. The tangent vectors should pass through the origin of the second which is p itself.
I copied this image from the internet. The points $p$ and $q$ are two different origins of two different spaces
  [image: Tangent space at different points]

Comment: How is $p$ the origin of $R^3$? Suppose we have the three-dimensional Euclidean space $R^3$ as usual and suppose the $S$ is a surface in the positive $x,y,z$ region of $R^3$ and $p$ a point on $S$ now it is necessary that the tangent plane to $S$ at $p$ will pass through the origin?

Comment: You are dealing with two different 3-dimensional spaces. The first is the one you are talking about and the second is the vector space generated by the tangent vectors and the normal vector. The tangent vectors should pass through the origin of the second which is p itself.