# How can tangent plane $T_{\textbf{p}}\textbf{S}$ of surface $S$ at point $\textbf{p}\in \textbf{S}$ can always pass through origin?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently reading Andrew Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry. It is written in Normals and Orientability, Chapter 4, Section 4.5, that

> Since tangent plane $T_{\textbf{p}}\textbf{S}$ of surface $S$ at point $\textbf{p}\in \textbf{S}$ passes through origin of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

In general, how is it possible for a tangent plane to always pass through the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

This question is also answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492931/tangent-plane-at-a-point-on-a-surface). In this response, it is stated that the point $\textbf{p}$ is the origin itself!! How is this possible when there could be an infinite number of such $\textbf{p}$ and thus an infinite number of origins!!!

Comment: according to the definition in your book, $T_pS$ indeed passes through the origin and doesn't have to pass through $p$. It is the plane tangent to $S$ at $p$, but translated to the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a formal isue which comes from the *definition* of tangent vectors and tangent spaces.

In Definition 1.1.5 the tangent vector of a parametrized curve $\gamma$ at time $t$ is introduced as the first derivative $\dot \gamma (t)$.

This concept is used in Definition 4.4.1 to define *tangent vectors* to a surface $\mathcal S$ at a point $p ∈ \mathcal S$ and the *tangent space* $T_p \mathcal S$ of $\mathcal S$ at $p$ as the set of all tangent vectors to $\mathcal S$ at $p$.

$T_p \mathcal S$ turns out to be a two-dimensional **linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$**. Hence it contains the origin.

I think you would prefer to understand the tangent space as the **affine subspace
$$A_p \mathcal S = p + T_p \mathcal S = \{ p + v \mid v \in T_p \mathcal S\}$$
of $\mathbb R^3$** which is obtained from $T_p \mathcal S$ by the translation on $\mathbb R^3$ shifting the origin to $p$. In fact $A_p \mathcal S$ is  the affine plane which deserves to be called the *geometric tangent plane to the surface $\mathcal S$ at the point $p \in \mathcal S$*. Be aware, however, that the essence of this geometric tangent plane lies in the linear space $T_p \mathcal S$.

The very origin of the concept of a tangent vector  of a curve $\gamma$ as the *derivative* $\dot \gamma (t)$ lies in elementary calculus. The usual motivation for introducing the derivative $f'(t)$ of a function  $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ at $t_0 \in (a,b)$ is to consider the graph of $f$ and the tangent line to that graph at the point $p_0 = (t_0,f(t_0)$. The derivative $f'(t_0)$ is then defined as the *slope of the tangent line*. This is just a real number, but it suffices to describe the tangent line although the slope does not refer to the point $p_0$ through which the tangent line is passing. We can say that that $f'(t_0)$ contains the essential information, the "origin" of the tangent line at $p_0$ is the trivial part.

Answer (score 1):

When you consider a point $\mathbf{p}\in S$ you want to approximate $S$ with a "linear object". In order to talk about linearity you need the origin.

Think about the Taylor polynomial at $x_0$ of degree $1$ for real functions (i.e. a tangent line). It is an affine function because it doesn't send $0$ to $0$, but if you shift the origin in $x_0$, then you have something linear.

So, it is not true that the tangent plane passes through the origin, but the tangent plane always passes through the point $\mathbf{p}$. If you perform the change of variables $\mathbf{x'=x-p}$ and you express $S$ in those cohordinates, then it passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then for each $p\in S$, $T_pS$ is a vector subspace of $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$. But, $T_p\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}^3$.